# Magento 2 on Mamp pro requires ext-mcrypt

Tags: php, magento, composer-php, mamp

I'm trying to install [Magento 2](https://magento.com/developers/magento2) on my MAMP PRO but I receive this error from composer:

```
*Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - magento/framework 100.0.4 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.0.4 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for magento/framework 100.0.4 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.4].*
```

But mcrypt is install in my MAMP:

[Screenshot of `phpinfo()` in my MAMP environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2kvw.png)

I tried adding the php version to `.bash_profile` file but it didn't resolve:

```
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin
export PATH="$MAMP_PHP:$PATH"
```

I try running php -i | grep mcrypt this is the result:
~/Sites/magento2  $ php -i | grep mcrypt

Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-png-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-freetype-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--prefix=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10' '--exec-prefix=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10' '--sysconfdir=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf' '--with-config-file-path=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--with-ldap' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-t1lib=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--enable-mbstring=all' '--with-curl=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-imap=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/imap-2007f' '--enable-soap' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-calendar' '--with-pgsql=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg' '--enable-exif' '--with-libxml-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-gettext=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-xsl=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg' '--with-mcrypt=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-openssl' '--enable-zip' '--with-iconv=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--enable-opcache' '--enable-cgi' '--enable-intl' '--with-icu-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-tidy=shared' '--enable-wddx' '--with-libexpat-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-readline' 'CFLAGS=-arch 'LDFLAGS=-arch 'LIBS=-lresolv' 'CXXFLAGS=-arch
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*

```
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

Comment: Command line PHP can/probably does in your case use a different configuration file. Try running `php -i | grep mcrypt` to see if it comes out in your CLI's configuration

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, running MAMP:
You need to find the php.ini file for the version of php you are running and replace the extension_dir line as below. (making sure to replace "php5.6.10" with your version and "no-debug-non-zts-20131226" with the name of the folder inside extensions.)

php.ini file usually located at: mamp/php/your-php-version/conf

```
extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/"
```

Comment: This answer rocks.